# Increase number of IP addresses returned by getaddrinfo

Tags: c, linux, dns, network-programming, ip

I'm using `getaddrinfo` to return the IP addresses for a URL input.

It's currently returning 8x IP addresses but I believe there are more.

If I call it again, it just returns the exact same addresses.

Is there a way to increase the number of IPs `getaddrinfo` returns?

OS: Ubuntu

Comment: What do you get if you query the same domain name using a DNS debugging utility (e.g. `dig`)?

Comment: @zwol Assuming you mean this: https://digwebinterface.com it returns 8x IPs which are different to the ones I was getting.

Comment: @zwol Ah you mean the Linux command `dig`. It returns the exact same 8x IP addresses as I got from `getaddrinfo`. However, I am very sure there are many many more and I wondered if it's possible to get the "nearest" 20/50 etc.

Comment: @zwol https://www.nslookup.io returns many different IPs too.

Comment: You're probably hitting a cache the second time you call getaddrinfo.  Have you tried using nslookup from the command line to connect to this domain's authoritative name server?  As others have said, (round robin) load balancing directly can mean the answer will change.  But let me ask this.... **what are you really trying to do?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any upper limit on the number of IP addresses produced by a single call to `getaddrinfo`.  If you are getting eight addresses, then eight addresses is how many there were in the DNS response.

If you get different IP addresses each time you call `getaddrinfo` with the same hostname, then that service is doing [DNS round-robin load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS) and you can call `getaddrinfo` many times to attempt to enumerate all available addresses.  Because DNS is  cached in many places throughout the network, you will need to space out your requests: I would drop down to a lower level DNS-specific API  (such as [c-ares](https://c-ares.org/)), contact the authoritative servers for the relevant DNS zone directly, and issue queries at a rate of one per minute or one per 150% of the server's declared response time-to-live, whichever is slower.  Yes, this is probably going to take hours.

If you get the *same* IP addresses each time you call `getaddrinfo` with the same hostname, but public DNS query services like `nslookup.io` and `digwebinterface.com` give you different addresses for that hostname, then the service is doing [DNS-based *geographic* load balancing](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/performance/what-is-dns-load-balancing/) and there is no practical way to enumerate all of the addresses for the hostname.

Note that there are ways to host multiple servers behind a single *IP address*, such as [reverse proxies](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy/) and [IP anycast](https://www.thousandeyes.com/learning/techtorials/anycast); just because you have all the addresses you can find, doesn't mean you have the ability to contact all available servers.